# Weld 001508 exception on Glassfish 4: how to ignore interface(s)?

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-rs, cdi, weld

Problem: I keep getting the WELD exception below when trying to deploy my WAR to Glassfish 4.1.1. The application deploys properly on Wildfly 9.0.

> Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: **WELD-001508: Cannot create an InjectionTarget from [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public abstract interface @Path class com.example.package.MyService as it is an interface**

Here, `MyService` is indeed an interface, defined in a separate library. My application pulls the library in so it can create a proxy against the `MyService` interface and make requests. `MyService` looks like:

```java
@Path("api")
public interface MyService {

    @GET
    public void someMethod();
}
```

I tried excluding `MyService` from WELD by adding the following to the `beans.xml` file, to no avail :(

```xml
<scan>
    <exclude name="com.example.package.*"></exclude>
</scan>
```

- Why is WELD trying to include that library's interface?
- How do I tell it to ignore it?

Comment: Do you happen to have a producer method defined for this interface?  I agree from this context its not really clear

Comment: No, no producer method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I didn't manage to find the root cause for this. However, I eventually got it to work by removing a bunch of Resteasy dependencies from the config file, which was probably the root cause of the problem. (For context, I was migrating from Wildfly/Resteasy onto Glassfish/Jersey).

At times, I still get this error (unsure why), but a clean and re-building of the package makes it go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to create `package-info.java` file and use `@Vetoed`:

```
@Vetoed
package com.example.package;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Vetoed;
```